# Transit visa from Amsterdam with Caribbean visa

Tags: transit, amsterdam, caribbean, sri-lankan-citizens

I'm visiting St. Maarten from Sri Lanka. I have a Caribbean visa from the Netherland Embassy. Transit period in Amsterdam Airport is 4 hours. Do I need a transit visa to go through Amsterdam?

Comment: I voted to leave the question open. With their special status, it's not completely obvious how oversees territory are treated. They are certainly not covered in the other question.

Comment: Can you tell us what airline(s) you're flying and/or if you know the terminals for your flight?

Comment: Schiphol, (Amsterdam airport) has only one 'air side' area, as the terminals are connected with a walkway air side as well as land side. Whether someone needs a transit visa while staying in that airport air side depends on nationality and sometimes visa for other countries.

Comment: PNuts and Relaxed, I don't get it. The question isn't about St Maarten or the visa for that, but simply the layover in Amsterdam. How is this not a duplicate?